# Duvida sobre a Classe Context

Tags: c#

No meu sistema tenho a classe `Context` para fazer a conexão com o Banco, através do Entity Framework e estou com uma duvida, só devo usar o `public DbSet<NomedaClasse> Classe {get; set;}` se eu estiver fazendo meu sistema pelo padrão Code First ou posso usá-lo normalmente? Desculpe a pergunta, sou novato em programação!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Entity;
using CadastroAtivos.Models;

namespace CadastroAtivos.DAL
{
    public class clsContext : DbContext
    {
        public clsContext() : base ("name=Stringconexao"){}

        public DbSet<clsMarcaModel> dbMarcas { get; set; }

        public DbSet<clsModeloModel> dbModelos { get; set; }
```

Comment: O que é usar normalmente? porque sempre deve usar normalmente, nunca irregularmente. Se você é novato em programação deve começar aprender primeiro os conceitos básicos, os fundamentos, para poder entender o resto. Embora possa parecer que está conseguindo fazer algo, sem entender tudo o que está acontecendo ali desde sua base pode estar fazendo tudo errado e nem tem condições de se dar conta dos erros. Não existe novato mexendo com EF, pelo menos não com propriedade, então é melhor voltar alguns passos antes.

Comment: Você pode configurar um Context e aponta-lo como chave unica de conexão no seu web.config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DbSet<T>` são a interpretação por meio de objetos das tabelas do seu banco de dados, independente de como foi a abordagem da implementação do seu contexto, seja ela Database First ou Code First.

Caso ainda não conheça o suficiente de EntityFramework, procure entendê-lo melhor acessando a documentação do Entity:

http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/what-is-entityframework.aspx

Answer (score 1):

No caso de um EF Database First, também existe um contexto, que é gerado e atualizado automaticamente toda vez que você atualiza o modelo do EDMX.

Comment: Desculpa a pergunta, o que seria EDMX?

Comment: EDMX é um arquivo XML e normalmente editado em uma interface grática, que reflete a estrutura da base de dados.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41599350/10991202